# Connect SSMS to AWS instance

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, ssms-2014

I'm using SSMS (SQL Server Management Studio) 2014 and trying to connect to an AWS instance which has SQL Server Express running. OS is Windows Server 2012 R2. All updates have been applied.

What I've done:

- Opened ports 1433, 1148 in AWS Security Group (firewall opened on inbound ports also on server)
- Enabled client protocols (TCP/IP, Named Pipes, Shared Memory) on server
- Remote server access enabled for database (server -> properties)
- SQL Server Browser enabled (server service)
- Public/Elastic IP assigned (ping works fine)
- Able to log into database on server just fine

The error I'm receiving:
Cannot connect to MYIPADDRESS\SERVERNAME,1148
The wait operation timed out

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

***EDIT***:
I've found the answer. I can connect with this string:
MYIPADDRESS\MSSQLSERVER,1433
And, of course, the proper credentials. I'd tried 'SQLSERVER', but not 'MSSQLSERVER'.

Zack

Comment: I'm not sure what does port 1148 has to do with this problem.  Ms sql server listens to 1433 and the sql browser service listens to 1434. Did you try using telnet to connect to port 1433?

Comment: I added 1148 because a buddy of mine said he uses that with SQL Server connections. Other than that, honestly, I have no idea. Yes, I can Telnet into the connection on the port 1433.

Answer (score 1):

Connection which worked: MYIPADDRESS\MSSQLSERVER,1433